# jQuery code not executing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**EDIT:** I solved it by doing

```
$(window).resize();
```

twice. Thanks for anybody who had an answer (I didn't see any at the time of editing)

I'm trying to make a page where a form is centered on the screen vertically and horizontally. I'm using this code:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){

            $(window).resize(function(){

                $('.centerscreen').css({
                    position:'absolute',
                    left: ($(window).width() 
                           - $('.centerscreen').outerWidth())/2,
                    top: ($(window).height() 
                          - $('.centerscreen').outerHeight())/2
                });

            });

            // To initially run the function:
            $(window).resize();

        });
```

The horizontal align works.
[image: horizontal align]
However, the vertical one only works after you resize the window
[image: vertical align]
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: doesnt css margin: auto solve this too ?

Comment: @Dwza: No, `margin:auto` works only for horizontal centering, not for vertical. But it _could_ be easily solved using the `display:table-…` types.

Comment: If you solved the issue, you should post it as an answer and accept it for others to benefit from later. Also, others will be able to comment on the solution and provide alternatives.

Comment: You shouldn't need to trigger the resize event more than once. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJgxD/) works fine with one call . Which jQuery version and browser are you testing in?